# Can you programmatically call a method as if it were a class field?

Tags: c#, class, oop, testing

I am writing an automated test suite for my program, and have been looking for ways to simplify and re factor a lot of the code.

Currently, I have a number of try/catch blocks (because I want to be able to move from one test to the next, even in the case of failure) that can log information otherwise. It looks a bit like this:

```
try
{
    PerformTest1();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    file.WriteLine("Unable to perform test number 1.");
    file.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
    file.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + e.StackTrace);
}

try
{
    PerformTest2();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    file.WriteLine("Unable to perform test number 2.");
    file.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
    file.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + e.StackTrace);
}
```

And so on. I was wondering if I could make an array of these tests, so I could use a loop. Something like:

```
foreach(Test t in testsArray)
{
    try
    {
        t.RunTest();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        file.WriteLine(t.failDescription);
        file.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        file.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + e.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

How can I execute this, but without making each test it's own class (with a RunTest() method)? I was thinking about making one test class, that has the necessary fields, one of them being a method. Then I could create a test object, and call that objects method. Is such a thing even possible? Or would I have to make multiple test classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a `Test` interface with a `runTest()` method, but you can implement the logic with anonymous classes or lambda expressions (if you are using Java 8), which would save you the need to create an explicit class for each test.

Example :

```
Test test1 = new Test () {
    public void runTest () {
    // logic of first test here
    }
};
```

Actually, you don't need to create your own interface. Use the existing `Runnable` interface with its `run()` method.

```
Runnable test1 = new Runnable () {
    public void run () {
    // logic of first test here
    }
};
```

or with a lambda expression :

```
Runnable test1 = () -> {
                        // logic of first test here
                       };
```

Then you can add each of these `Runnable`s to a list (or array) and run them in a loop, as you wanted :

```
for (Runnable test in testsArray)
{
    try {
       test.run();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I never accepted this, I ended up using a similar approach. Inside the Test class, I created a virtual method called `RunTest` that was overridden for each of my tests, and used that to run and log them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use some Lambda tricks:

```
var actions = new List<Action>();
actions.Add(PerformTest1);  // requires a void PerformTest1() method
actions.Add(PerformTest2);
//...  and so on...
```

and then finally fire all actions:

```
foreach(var action in actions)
{
   action();
}
```

Comment: You aren't using any lambada here, just delegates.

Comment: Yeah... I know... In the first version I used a lambda but then I double-checked the solution in VS to prevent some typos. And that was the moment where ReSharper kicked in and simplified the code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface Testable {
    void doTest();
}
public class Test1 implements Testable {
    // implement doTest()
}
private static Testable[] testables = new Testabable[] {
    new Test1()
};
// now iterate your testables and call doTest()
```

Ok, seems to be old school, but it's the first thing, one should learn about interfaces.

Comment: In .Net, it is considered best practice to name interfaces with I as the initial letter so `Testable` should be `ITestable`

Comment: @Chris: ah, ok. In Java this would be bad Style. Funny thing.

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot of small different naming conventions that still trip me up (I came from a primarily Java background but now work with .Net). Same concept behind the interfaces though, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the available testing frameworks for .Net/ Java? I believe Nunit (or JUnit) provides much of the functionality you are looking for, including writing out the stack trace and exception details in the event of a failure.

The also encapsulate multiple tests within a test fixture, so will allow you to still execute subsequent tests after a failure without bleeding data or state between your individual tests.

Comment: I'm using TestStack.White, an automated UI testing framework for .Net. I like it a lot actually. I'm not sure what sort of 'Test' interfaces it offers though, will definitely look into that.